# Overactivity in one muscle of the agonist-antagonist pair and eventual desirability in athletes

Tags: exercise, exercise-technique, hypertrophy, physiology

I used to be an amateur athlete until I was 16 and I was diagnosed with brain cancer in which case I was left wheelchair-bound because of paresis in my left leg and inability to step on it. I was left with equinus foot too.

My left calf is just gigantic and very strong.

My physician(physiatrist-physical rehabilitation medicine) explained the reason and out of curiosity I studied more of it.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11723864
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26027752

**I am curious as to whether a trainer could induce overactivity by just targeting one muscle of the pair and devoting himself to train that one muscle and forsaking the other muscle in the pair and whether it would be desirable in a professional athlete?**

Comment: That...would depend mightily on which sport the athlete is competing in.

Comment: @JohnP It was first and foremost whether physiology allows it, i.e will doing this(training only one muscle in the pair) result in the overactivity seen a paretic patients. And only secondly if it would be desirable. I mean in Basketball players Tibialis Anterior does not seem to do much. Nor do the Hamstrings. Or Psoas and Iliacus. Or Biceps. Or the Exterior  Muscles in the Ulna and Radius(the interior muscles are usefull for grabbing). As for the body trunk i feel it is quitte hard to train Abdominals, Back, Chest, Shoulders(all of those 4) without training their respective antagonists.

Comment: @JohnP Speaking about Basketball how important is the Tibialis Anterior compared to the Calves, how important are the Hamstrings compared to the Quadriceps, how Important are Psoas and Iliacus compared to the glutes, how important are the Biceps compared to the Triceps how important are the Exterior muscles in lower arm compared to the Interior muscles? But first and foremost the question was about the physiology not about the desirability. The desirability was a second minor part.